# Django ModelForm for Multiple Categories of a Product in EAV data model

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, entity-attribute-value

Hello all I am making auction website like ebay, I have this model design which has many other extra attributes model classes for different categories. But here let's take an example of a PC one which will be used for its sub-categories Desktop and Laptop.

Now the problem, I want to create ModelForm for users. For instance if user selects Desktop as their product to put on auction, how will that modelform code look like? So the Desktop respected fields are given to the user to fill from the extra_pc_attributes class? The problem is that, wouldn't it get tedious to write separate modelform for each category and also in the views.py use those as objects.

Maybe use Jsonfield instead of creating a whole EAV old-fashioned table for extra attributes? But I am new and I don't know how it will work or even if it applies to this situation.

```
class Categories(MPTTModel):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

class auction_product(models.Model):  
product_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
date_added = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
user = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='product_ownership', related_name='product_user')
product_bid = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='bid', related_name='product_bid')
product_comment = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='comment')
album = models.OneToOneField(ImageAlbum, related_name='product_model', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
def __str__(self):
    return self.product_name

    #Extra PC Attributes
class extra_pc_attributes(auction_product):
    processor = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    ram = models.FloatField()
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    motherboard = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    case = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    screen_size = models.FloatField()
    weight = models.FloatField()
```

Comment: You can represent attribute as a separate model. Where the attribute would have a name, and a type, and the values that this attribute can take as another model which can depend on the type of the attribute.

Comment: Is it good performance-wise? I like your idea

Comment: I have said this in context to e-commerce frameworks in django, in particular I have used [django-oscar](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/3.0a/) and know it uses this kind of models.